# Do Heegaard Floer homology detect fibred knot in general oriented 3-manifold?

Tags: reference-request, 3-manifolds

Do Heegaard Floer homology detect fibred knot in general oriented 3-manifolds other than $S^3$? If the answer is yes could you give a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known for any knot in a closed, oriented 3-manifold whose complement is irreducible.  Ni proved this in [Knot Floer homology detects fibred knots](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607156), building on [Ghiggini](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603445)'s proof in the genus 1 case; another proof was given by [Juhász](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609779) (see theorem 9.11).